# How to draw a line on a canvas using fabric.js

Tags: jquery, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am using fabric.js to draw a line on a canvas. This is my code, but I'm not getting any output:

```
$("#Line").click(function() {
    // alert("Line");
    canvas.add(new fabric.Line([50, 100, 200, 200], {
        left: 170,
        top: 150,
        fill: 'red'
    }));
});
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Simple change: You can't `fill` a line with a color in fabric.js. You have to use `stroke` with a color instead.

In the snippet below `fill:'red'` is replaced with `stroke:'red'`.

```
$("#Line").click(function () {
    // alert("Line");
    canvas.add(new fabric.Line([50, 100, 200, 200], {
        left: 170,
        top: 150,
        stroke: 'red'
    }));
});
```

Comment: @sanjaynakate: I will +1 if you add some detail about what is different in your code snippet vs. the OP's code snippet. As is neither the question or answer is very useful. Remember that these answers are meant to help others, not just the OP. Thanks!

Comment: @PaulSasik simple you cant fill:'red' line in fabric.js  we have to use stroke:'red' thanks...

Comment: @sanjaynakate: Yes, the answer was quite simple but it took me a while of looking at the code to see the difference. See my edit to your answer, based on your comment by the way.

Comment: That library is such a pain... Where is the documentation for that type of things? Full of bugs. When I dig into a function, there is a bug. Just to say, when looking for drawing a line with fabricjs, the most accurate answer I can find is this post. So +10000 if I could ^^

Comment: @Sanjay Nakate, nop, I gave up, I finally just used canvas to draw dynamically some lines and the rest with CSS.

Comment: Fabric is great but the docs are some of the least friendly I've ever used. Just trying to establish what arguments a method takes can be a real ball ache. Where, for example, on [the page for the `Line()` constructor](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Line.html#initialize), does it even say what order the points should be passed in?

Comment: the documentation is really terrrible