# How to a draw line

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I just want to draw a line with Fabric.js, but I don't understand how the constructor works. It says:

`initialize(points, options)`

```
canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', { selection: false, backgroundColor:'#eee' });
slab=new fabric.Rect({ 
  left:100,
  top:100,
  width:700,
  height:400,
  fill:'#c0c0c0',
  originX: 'left', 
  originY: 'top',
  centeredRotation: true,
  selectable:false
});
canvas.add(slab);
line=new fabric.Line([0,0, 200,200], {
    strokeDashArray: [2, 2],
    stroke: 'navy'
});
canvas.add(line);
console.log('X1:'+line.x1+', Y1:'+line.y1+', X2: '+line.x2+', Y2: '+line.y2);
console.log('L:'+line.left+', T:'+line.top+', W: '+line.width+', H: '+line.height);
```

And I got this result on the console:

```
X1:0, Y1:0, X2: 200, Y2: 200
L:100, T:100, W: 200, H: 200
```

**So how it works if it is not
*new fabric.Line([point1.x,point1.y, point2.x,point2.y], options)* ?**

*Note: I have already some rectangles in my canvas*

Comment: checkout this link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18835580/how-to-draw-a-line-on-a-canvas-using-fabric-js/18835620#18835620

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly Fabric uses `top/left/width/height` properties for most of its objects and they are defined in general `Object` class, but the `Line` class defines additionally a `p1 and p2` points.

When you want to modify a `Line` you need to change its points, but some of the Fabric internal functionality is still based on general `Object` interfaces. The `Fabric.Line` setters will not update `t/l/w/h` properties when you modify one of its points. In such case, when you see some strange errors in `Line` behavior you should run a `setCoords` method, which should update all the fields it needs internally.